# How to refer to the value of a controlwrapper somewhere else in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I have various controlwrapper dropdowns. How can I use what is currently being displayed in the dropdown within an if statement for another function. 
The controlwrapper I want to access value:

```
    var GenderPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'control2',
    dataTable: columnsTable,
    options: {
        filterColumnLabel: 'colLabel',
        ui: {
            label: 'Data Type: ',
            allowTyping: false,
            allowMultiple: false,
            allowNone: false,
            selectedValuesLayout: 'belowStacked'
        }
    },
    state: initState
});
```

*Note: This is actually a little different than the regular dropdown to get the specific values I wanted.*

Progressing on this, is it possible to separately define more than one colorAxis: colors array dependent on the value of this controlwrapper. So that the color scale of a geochart changes depending on what value is selected. So that I can have pink for female, blue for male, etc.
eg.

```
var color1 = [];
var color2 = [];

function somefunction(){
if (controlwrapper == specific value){
color1 = ['#FFF000', etc]
} else if (controlwrapper == specific value 2){
color2 = ['#FF0000', etc]
...etc
}
}
```

Then in the options variable of the chart:

```
colors: color1
```

Is what i'm trying to get here for a geochart even possible?

EDIT: I have been able to get the colors that I want in the arrays depending on the value of the dropdown. These are assigned to a variable which I will hopefully be used in the colors: option.
code used:

```
var color1;
    if (state.selectedValues.toString() == "Value1"){
      color1 = ['#000000','#00FF00','#FF0000','#0000FF']
    } else if (state.selectedValues.toString() == "Value2"){
      color1 = ['#FFFFFF','#00FF00','#FF0000','#000000']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this a fair bit of trial and error. By no way is it the most efficient method but was reasonably easy to understand and debug.

Firstly, I had to work out where the change (pressing of dropdown) was occurring, this was fairly simple due to other state change listeners.

```
    function setChartView() {
    var state = GenderPicker.getState();
    if (state.selectedValues.toString() == "Total Youth Unemployment Rate"){
      color1.splice(0,4)
      value1.splice(0,4)
      color1.push('#444444','#EEFFC8','#71A400','#3B5600')
      value1.push(0,0.00001,30, 70)
    } else if (state.selectedValues.toString() == "Male Youth Unemployment Rate"){
      color1.splice(0,4)
      value1.splice(0,4)
      color1.push('#444444','#C8EEFF','#0071A4','#003B56')
      value1.push(0,0.00001,30, 70)
    } else if (state.selectedValues.toString() == "Female Youth Unemployment Rate"){
      color1.splice(0,4)
      value1.splice(0,4)
      color1.push('#444444','#FFC8EE','#A40071','#56003B')
      value1.push(0,0.00001,30, 70)
    }
    geoChart.setView(view);
    geoChart.draw();
  }
```

Then I simply created 3 `if-then-elseif` statements which queried the current state's `selectedValues` for a specified string. This was for each of my 'dropdown options'. I would guess that a loop could be implemented here for simpler code, but I haven't gotten around to that yet.
To get the colors I wanted, some array manipulation was needed. The process was as follows:

```
      color1.splice(0,4) //This removes any items in the color1 array that were already present.
      value1.splice(0,4) //This removes any items in the value1 array that were already present.
      color1.push('#444444','#EEFFC8','#71A400','#3B5600') //This adds the new colours to now blank color1 array.
      value1.push(0,0.00001,30, 70) //This adds the values to the now blank value1 array.
```

If `splice()` is not used the arrays will just get bigger as `push()` appends not replaces. To keep consistency, `splice()` needs to be used.

These arrays are defined before the chart options.

```
var color1 = [];
var value1 = [];
```

And in the chart options specified the above variables in the `colorAxis`.

```
var options1 = { 
        title: 'A', 
        displayMode: 'regions', 
        datalessRegionColor: 'C0C0C0', 
        colorAxis: { 
            values: value1,
            colors: color1
        } 
    };
```

I did not understand why I had to specify a values array each time because they were the same throughout instead of explicitly just stating it in the colorAxis. It was giving me a different length error so I just decided to do the same with it as colors.

Will update with fiddle when I get time later today.